# I am adding constraints to the imageview. But it is not showing

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints

I have added constraints to [the pill image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjtAw.png). I have added Horizontally centre constraint. But when I change the screen, it shows like this. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: add Contraint from up side , margin , aspect Ratio and than add Center Horizontal.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Horizontal centre constraint, top, height and width to imageView.

Answer (score 0):

Auto Layout defines your user interface using a series of constraints. Auto Layout then calculates the size and location of each view based on these constraints. Auto layout requires constraints in terms of size(width, height) and location(x, y). You have added horizontal centre (x location constraint), now it needs top(y position), width and height constraint to calculate the exact position. Refer the image below

[image]